# SQL - Define/Modify XML with variables

Tags: sql, xml

I'm trying to define an XML variable with VARCHAR characters inside of it...

Example

```
DECLARE @number nvarchar(10);
SET @number = '10'


DECLARE @xml XML;
SET @xml = 
'
<Root>
  <Node> Hello {sql:variable("@number")} </Node>
</Root>
'
```

However, the problem is that you can only set xml variables to string literals. Is there any way of doing this? Thanks!

Comment: Is concatenation not an option?

`SET @xml = 
'
<Root>
  <Node> Hello ' + @number + '</Node>
</Root>
'`

Comment: as a note if the variable is null `@xml` will be null in the above example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure why you want to do this. Use `+` to concatenate the variable inside the string then assign it to `xml` varibale

```
DECLARE @number NVARCHAR(10);

SET @number = '10'

DECLARE @xml XML;

SET @xml = '
<Root>
  <Node> Hello ' + Isnull(@number,'') + ' </Node>
</Root>
'
```

To view the xml

```
select @xml
```

Result :

```
<Root>
  <Node> Hello 10 </Node>
</Root>
```

Comment: if `@number` is `null` then `@xml` will be set to `null`

Comment: @MatthewWhited - Handled it. Still I feel your answer is right way to do it.

Comment: I would not suggest to create XML via string concatenation!

Answer (score 2):

```
DECLARE @number nvarchar(10) = '10';

DECLARE @xml XML = N'';    
SELECT @xml = @xml.query('
<Root>
  <Node>Hello {sql:variable("@number")}</Node>
</Root>
');

SELECT @xml;

/*
<Root>
  <Node>Hello 10</Node>
</Root>
*/
```

Comment: yeah... the other way felt dirty so I had to figure this out.

Comment: This works, but is cutting an apple with a chain saw... - wrong tool...

Comment: How is doing something the correct way wrong?  And a "hello world" type of example such as this is how you understanding a thing.  It's probably a pretty safe bet that the real XML that OP is trying to update/modify will be much more complex than this.

Comment: I did not say this is wrong... And I think that you are right, that this is a good and simple example to explain this techique. And I do believe, that this is a simplified example of the real world needs. Especially the last point lets me think, that this is the wrong tool. I'd use `xml.query()` to transform/query *existing XML* with `FLWOR-queries`, but I would not *build XML from scratch*. If there is a more complex scenario (nestings, 1:n, namespaces) you will get into troubles soon...

Comment: After some thinking I voted yours up. It is a working and correct example, the rest is opinion / demands depending...

Answer (score 1):

In my eyes the existing answers (upvoted and accepted) are no good paths to go. One should (almost) never create XML via string concatenation...

Why not the simple way? Let the XML-engine do the hard work!

```
DECLARE @number nvarchar(10);
SET @number = '10'

DECLARE @xml XML=(SELECT 'Hello ' + @number FOR XML PATH('Node'),ROOT('Root'),TYPE);

SELECT @xml;
```

Returns

```
<Root>
  <Node>Hello 10</Node>
</Root>
```

Just imagine, your (string!) variable includes some text with forbidden characters (`><&` or qoutes or one of the many special / far east / whatever characters)... Using `FOR XML ...` will implicitly do all the escaping for you...

One side effect: If your variable is `NULL` you will not get a `NULL` for all, but a valid XML with an empty node:

```
<Root>
  <Node />
</Root>
```

Comment: How is this cleaner than my example?

Comment: @MatthewWhited I must admit this is neither cleaner nor better, just easier with a more complex scenario...

Comment: that's debatable... and still using string concat that you were complaining about.

Comment: @MatthewWhited Yes, you are right again. That's debateable (and heavily depending on the actual needs)... But you are not right, that this string-concatenation is *XML building*. I'm against `DECLARE @xml XML='<root>' + @SomeString + </root>`, because the content of `@SomeString` might break this completely. While `SELECT ... FOR XML ...` will create predictable results. (Btw: Your approach is *safe* in this point of view too. It's only the currently accepted answer, which is *bad* in my eyes.

Comment: It's all good... I'm just giving you crap.  I often use the pattern you show above and the fact I had to create a nonnull XML variable and then reuse it makes mine a little weird as well.  But then again this is TSQL so there will always be sacrifices :)

Comment: @MatthewWhited `*grin*` and Happy Coding